# Measure of Central Tendancy - Modal Class Identification

Tags: statistics, central-tendency

I have been studying Measure of Central Tendency where we need find `Mean, Median and Mode`

I have problems finding the modal class in Mode calculation.
I would like to know when to use the `inspection method` and when to use the `Grouping method`

The question is something similar.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "inspection mode" and "grouping mode"? Are you asking which representation of the data is better for calculating the mode?

Comment: yes that's my question

Comment: But what are these methods about? I can't find anything about them online.

Comment: Please follow this link http://www.economicsdiscussion.net/central-tendency/how-to-calculate-the-mode-in-2-different-series/2497

Comment: I guess that the grouping method is better for an interpolation? But I really don't understand why you couldn't simply always use inspection,

Comment: There are things which needs to be considered. What if there is sudden spikes in the frequency?

Comment: I don’t see why that would affect anything. Perhaps we’re considering different concepts?